# rails Stripe connect Oauth hanging on callback link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, oauth-2.0, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

So I'm not really getting an error other than the fact that the browser is timing out. Any help with this would be great. I am using the `gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect', '>= 2.4.0'`. I think this is all of the relevant code for this but If you need any other code let me know.

link i'm sending user to stripe with

```
<%= link_to image_tag('stripe.png'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:stripe_connect) %>
```

routes for callback

```
get '/auth/stripe_connect/callback', to: 'stripe_connect#create'
```

redirect url in stripe connect settings

```
https://example.com/auth/stripe_connect/callback
```

Answer (score 0):

my redirect url in stripe settings needed the www. because i hadn't redirected the naked domain.

```
https:www.example.com/auth/stripe_connect/callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Put http://localhost:3000/users/auth/stripe_connect/callback in redirect development in Stripe dashboard.